# Does anyone have a wrapper for STL algorithms, taking one container instead of two iterators as first argument?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, iterator, wrapper

Does anyone know of a header file, or has taken the time to wrap all algorithms themselves?

Ie

```
std::fill(iterator start, iterator stop, value_type val) ->
xxx::fill(container& c, value_type val)
```

Update:
Seems boost [range does](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) exactly what I want.

Comment: Because I am to lazy to write it myself

Comment: But why?  What is so hard about writing begin and end?

Comment: Takes up horizontal space, harder to read, takes time and i'm tired of it, in 99% of the cases I am using the whole range anyway.

Comment: It's not harder to read if you're writing C++, because the whole Standard Library and Boost is using this

Comment: @Nikko: not the whole of Boost, since Boost.Range includes versions of the algorithms that do operate on ranges, and containers are ranges.

Comment: @Nikko: You seriously dont think std::fill(c, val); gives better readability than std::fill(c.begin(), c.end(), val); ?

Comment: A nice use for this kind of thing is with std::copy, to copy from one temporary container into another. For example, IMO `xxx::copy( get_container(), target_container)` is neater than `auto temp = get_container(); std::copy(temp.begin(),temp.end(),target_container);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost Range

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html